# Does Google Identity Platform have a local emulator?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-identity

I would like to know if there is an emulator for local development and if there is documentation about it.

I know Firebase has one but I don't know if it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, there's no emulator feature for Google Cloud Identity Platform (GCIP) yet. As reference, this is also mentioned on a Google Groups [thread](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/fAlVKmNfPIc). Currently there is no ETA when this feature would be available in the future. These are the current [beta emulators](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators) that are available .

What I could suggest is file a feature request through this link to [report issues and feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).